# Alternative to drools-planner/optaplanner in c++/c#?

Tags: c++, optimization, constraint-programming, drools-planner, optaplanner

is there an comparable alternative for optaplanner/drools planner in C++ or C#?
I only found a very old C# portation of 2007.
Or how do you solve NP-hard optimization problems in C++/C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) mailing list, people have asked about using OptaPlanner from .NET before.

If you're interested in pursuing that direction (and it fits within your requirements), here were some of the idea's:

- In Java, expose an OptaPlanner implementation as a REST service (with RestEasy and/or Camel). Map the domain objects to XML with JAXB (or XStream). Then use a C# client to contact that REST service.
- From C#, call a command that starts a java app which reads an XML file as input and writes one as output. Again, use JAXB (or XStream) to serialize that XML.
- Directly call Java from C# using something like IKVM.

Answer (score 2):

[Google or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools) is implemented in C++ but has a number of bindings in other languages like C#. I've used the C# bindings and it works absolutely fine. The version downloaded through nuget.org didn't work for me, though it worked fine when I downloaded the software and manually referenced it from my project.